# My website doesn't allow third-party keyboards from iOS

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, ios-keyboard-extension

When I create websites with input fields and I view them on an iphone, the default keyboard always pops up in spite of the fact that I use a third-party keyboard called swype as my default keyboard. Is there a certain attribute I need to put in my input tag so that it allows third-party keyboards? If not, how would I allow them? Let me know. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
<div id="project-input" class="col-sm-6">
  <input id="project-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title Your Project">
</div> <!--col-sm-6 -->
```

Comment: This sounds more like an iOS issue than an HTML issue. I can't imagine server code that will change the keyboard that pops up on your device, save localized/language related code...

Comment: Gotacha, thanks @TimS!

Comment: I'm not a web developer, but perhaps all your textfields are marked as secure text entry? This switches back to the system keyboard by default. Also, if you're using Chrome, they recently disabled keyboard extensions.